# Qt Project in VS2008 Always Rebuilds

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2008, moc

I have a Qt5.3 project running in Visual Studio 2008 with the Qt Plugin.
Every time I Run the project, it builds itself from scratch without any changes being made between runs.

I generated the project with the VS wizard, so I don't have any custom steps added.
Any ideas ?

Comment: could you show your .pro-file?

Comment: I don't have it on this PC, but it's just as Visual Studio generates it when I create a new console application. I forgot to mention that I tried the same thing under Visual Studio 2013, and only the changes compile (as expected). And it's not a .pro file, but a vcproj.